# Matlab Type cast in C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to write the Matlab Type cast function in C++.  In Matlab it goes as follows:

```
>> format long e
>> d=typecast(uint32([65304 47886]), 'double')

d =

1.016138904784275e-309
```

Where the HEX is given as

```
0000bb0e0000ff18
```

In C++, I have done this

```
double d = 65304+ ((uint64_t)47886<<32);
std::cout << "d " << "is " <<  d << std::endl;

d  is 2.05669e+14
```

In HEX that is  0000bb0e0000ff18

So, why do I get different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really typecasting the result, you're just doing a type conversion so the double value you get is the same as the integer value.

If you want to do a true [`typecast`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) as in MATLAB, you'll need to do something like this:

```
unsigned long i = 65304 + ((uint64_t)47886<<32);
// Make the double pointer address the same memory as the integer
double *d = (double *)&i;
std::cout << "d " << "is " <<  *d << std::endl;
```

The problem is that you're going to run into problems with portability because this solution requires the number of bits in the int type to equal the number of bits in the float type exactly.

Result (on my machine):

```
d is 1.01614e-309
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at your operation in the C++ code you will see that you only sum two integer values:

```
double d = 65304 + ((uint64_t)47886<<32);
--> d = 65304 + 205668803936256;
--> d = 205668804001560
```

And this is the result you get in your code. So if you want to interpret this value as a flouting point number you have to convert this hex value into a floating point encoding

[Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Maybe a cast will not be enough for your results. And you have to read the bits for the sign, exponent and fraction directly out of the hex format.